# Foreign key issue while inserting data in child table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I am trying to insert data in **orders** table and then save order details in **order_details** table. Following is the code that I'm trying

```
$order = Order::create($request->all());
$order->order_detail()->insert($request->order_detail); //$request->order_detail is an array
```

In my model I have provided relationships

Order Model

```
public function order_detail(){
   return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Order Detail Model

```
public function order(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Order::class,'order_id');
}
```

but it returns me  **General error: 1364 Field 'order_id' doesn't have a default value** as order_id is a foreign  key in **order_details** table

How can I do it without giving order_id manually

Comment: What do you see when you do `dd($request->order_detail)`?

Comment: @Digvijay array:2 [ 0 => array:4 [ "product_id" => 32 "qty" => 4 "price" => "470.00" "details" => "Recusandae voluptas earum praesentium esse iure dignissimos. Deleniti rerum voluptatem debitis et non et. Dolorem reiciendis quia qui et omnis aut." ] 1 => array:4 [ "product_id" => 32 "qty" => 4 "price" => "470.00" "details" => "Recusandae voluptas earum praesentium esse iure dignissimos. Deleniti rerum voluptatem debitis et non et. Dolorem reiciendis quia qui et omnis aut." ] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that `$request->order_detail` is an array of many `order_details`.

The problem with `insert` is that you are not using Eloquent but the query builder, therefore Laravel is not able to fill the `order_id` by itself, if you use `createMany` instead it will be able to do so:

```
$order = Order::create($request->all());
$order->order_detail()->createMany($request->order_detail);
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method):

> You may use the createMany method to create multiple related models:

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->createMany([
    [
        'message' => 'A new comment.',
    ],
    [
        'message' => 'Another new comment.',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Since your `$request->order_detail` isn't gonna contain order_id. You can take that from the newly created $order.

```
$order = Order::create($request->all()); // upon create, you can access the order_id by doing $order->id

$orderDetails = [];

foreach($request->order_detail as $details) {
    $orderDetails[] = [
        array_merge($details, ['order_id' => $order->id]);
    ];
}

$order->order_detail()->insert($orderDetails);
```

Comment: is there any way that Laravel can get **order_it** by it self ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a database issue. The column `order_id` has AUTO_INCREMENT, meaning it would generate a number upon insert.

Try inserting with phpMyAdmin to see whether AUTO_INCREMENT works. Or use SHOW TABLE STATUS and check AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: No, it's not auto-increment. order_id  is unassigned